# jQuery serialize function with multple forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm using the jQuery .serialize function and can't get it to serialize the proper form on submit.

my js code:

```
    function getquerystring(form) {
    return $("form").serialize();
}
```

my forms:

```
<div class="leave_message_box">
    <form name="leave_message_form">
        <input type="text" name="clock_code" placeholder="Clock Code" />
    <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message (Blank for none)"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="leave_message" />
        <input value="Leave Message" type="button" onclick='JavaScript:xmlhttpPost("clockin.php", "leave_message_form")'></p>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="outside_job_box">
    <form name="outside_job_form">
        <input type="text" name="clock_code" placeholder="Clock Code" />
    <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message (Blank for none)"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="ouside_job" />
        <input value="Outside Job" type="button" onclick='JavaScript:xmlhttpPost("clockin.php", "outside_job_form")'></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

I must be doing something wrong in passing the variable.  the full code @ [pastie](http://pastie.org/691881).  The function I have does work, however, its always the last form that gets submitted.

Comment: +1 for supplying the full code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this code:

```
$("form")
```

will find all the `<form>` elements in your document.

Given that `form` is a string containing the *name* of the form, what you want instead is this:

```
$("form[name='" + form + "']")
```

Looking at your supplied code, I have this suggestion. Instead of passing the form name to your function, why not just pass the form itself?

```
<button onclick="xmlhttpPost('blah', this.form)">
```

You also don't need to put `javascript:` in the `onclick`, `onfocus`, `onwhatever` properties.

Comment: perfect, that worked like a charm.  I removed the `javascript` changed to `this.form` and used `$(form).serialize();`.  Thank you for the help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting an ID attribute on the form and then using that ID as an explicit selector for jQuery:

```
<div class="outside_job_box">
  <form id="outside_job_form" name="outside_job_form">
      <input type="text" name="clock_code" placeholder="Clock Code" />
      <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message (Blank for none)"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="type" value="ouside_job" />
      <input value="Outside Job" type="button" onclick='JavaScript:xmlhttpPost("clockin.php", "outside_job_form")'></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Then you would select and serialize it like this;

```
var f = $("#outside_job_form").serialize();
```

Not only making your code more effecient but more readable, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If the sole purpose is to encode simple text into URL format then use [encodeURIComponent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp).